# Kubernetes/Azure ACS: Why can't I access external IPs of my Service?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

Using Kubernetes on Azure Container Service (not the new AKS though).

I'm deploying a front-end up like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: etc/etc
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: frontend
```

I can see that it's started correctly from the logs.

From `kubectl get services` I can see that it has been assigned an External IP. But when I try to access that via HTTP it just hangs.

I also can see in the Azure Portal that the Azure Load Balancer was created and is pointing to the correct external IP and backend pool.

Can anyone tell me if I somehow messed up the port assignments in the pod definition?

--

Update: Somehow it started working on it's own (or seemed like). But when I tried to re-create it as a Service instead of Deployment it stopped working

Here's my Service:

This is my config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: meteor
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http-server
  selector:
    app: frontend
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

It creates the external IP for the load balancer, and I can see that it is properly matching the pods. but I get a timeout when I try to connect to the external IP. Meanwhile the load balancer that was created as part of the deployment continues to work just fine.

Comment: It seems to have started working suddenly. I wonder if there was some service problems with Azure. Will update if anything else comes up.

Comment: If you need more help with ACS, please let me know:)

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT thanks! do you know how to change the agent VM size in an existing ACS deployment?

Comment: Still having an issue with newly created load balancers hanging.

Comment: Could you please run this command `kubectl get service` to check the status.

Comment: meteor                          LoadBalancer   10.0.108.137   13.88.27.165    80:32532/TCP     4m

Comment: could you please show your new docker file in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158926/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-hexsprite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was a mis-specification of the targetPort. Adjusting it to the correct value and replacing the Service definition solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> do you know how to change the agent VM size in an existing ACS
>   deployment?

We can change k8s agent via Azure portal, the agent in Azure is a VM, we should **resize** the VM :

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey actually I'm still having the same issue as the original question. It stopped working again and I can't figure out why ;)